# Wagtail Django admin model multiple images from orderable

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a Location Model:

```
class Location(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)

    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    address = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=misc_options.STATES, null=True, blank=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=False)

    lat = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    lon = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=False)
    places_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    google_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    entity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    truck_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    trailer_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    supplies_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel("name"),
            InlinePanel('location_images'),
        ], heading="Store Info"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('city'),
            FieldPanel('state'),
            FieldPanel('zipcode'),
            FieldPanel('lat'),
            FieldPanel('lon'),
        ], heading="Location Info"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('phone'),
            FieldPanel('email'),
            FieldPanel('facebook_url'),
            FieldPanel('google_url'),
        ], heading="Contact Info"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('entity'),
            FieldPanel('truck_url'),
            FieldPanel('trailer_url'),
            FieldPanel('supplies_url'),
        ], heading="Web Self Storage Info"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('places_id'),
        ], heading="Google Places Info"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('features'),
        ], heading="Features Info"),
    ]

    class Meta:  # noqa
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Location Detail"
        verbose_name_plural = "Location Details"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

that is an Admin Model. I need to attach multiple images to each object in this model. I do this using a foreign key field with "Feature", but this makes all of the features available for each location, and the features have to be edited from a separate interface. I don't want this with Images.

I have an image Orderable model:

```
class LocationImages(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey("location.LocationPage", related_name="location_images")
    location_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel("location_image"),
    ]
```

but I'm stuck because ParentalKey shouldn't point to a page, it should point to the Location model, if I am not mistaken. I assume a manytoone relationship is the best route, but I don't see that option when I run dir() on modelcluster.fields. There isn't any documentation that I can find on modelcluster.

what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that ParentalKey is pretty smart. It will take a model name as the binding object instead of a page. I also changed my Location model to a ClusterableModel. Migrated, and it works.

```
class Location(ClusterableModel, models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    ...
```

and

```
class LocationImages(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(Location, related_name="location_images")
    ...
```